# sbt 1.9 issue with spark 3.4.1 in Intellij with scala 3.3.0 version

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I have installed 1.9 SBT & intellij . now, I want to configure spark 3.4.1 version with 3.3.0 scala version in Intelliji by using below code in built.sbt

[image]

Is there any solution of it ??

Thank you

[image]

I was expecting it to get succeeed but encountered error

Comment: In IntelliJ, in the build panel, click on the 4 lines, one of them should have a more explicit error message. Or just run SBT from CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no release published compatible with `scala 3.3.0` for [spark-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core) or any other version of `spark-core`.

Just changing

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.3.0"
```

For

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.11"
```

Should fix your problem. You can also use `scala 2.12.x`

---

You have these links to read more about that combination:

- [Scala 3 and Spark?](https://medium.com/virtuslab/scala-3-and-spark-389f7ecef71b)

> After the release of Scala 3, one of the most common questions asked by developers was: “When will we be able to write Spark jobs using Scala 3?”.
> Up till now, the answer was: “Not yet” but everything changed after the release of Spark 3.2.0, which brought Scala 2.13 support. Scala 3 projects can depend on Scala 2.13 libraries, so can we finally write Spark jobs using Scala 3? The answer is yes, in theory

- [github repo spark-scala3](https://github.com/vincenzobaz/spark-scala3)

> This repository aims at making the adoption of Scala 3 easier for projects using Apache Spark

Comment: Thanks Gaston . I changed scala version to 2.13.11 and spark version of 3.2.2 with 1.9 sbt version and it worked for me.

Comment: spark `3.2.2` is a bit old. If you are starting a new project, I suggest to use the latest one. In case you need to deal with a legacy one, you can use the version you need for that. Just keep in mind to keep updated the version of your dependencies to avoid security issues and incompatibility between them